# Text capacity exceeded with beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create a frame which contain these lines :

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Traduction automatique statistique}
   En appliquant la règle de Bayes, l'expression ci-dessus peut être réécrite comme suit :
    \begin{block}
    \begin{equation}
    \hat{e} = \arg\max_{e} P(f | e) P(e) 
  \end{equation}
     \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

But when I compile it i get this error :

> Text capacity exceeded , sorry [input stack size = 5000] \end frame

Any idea please?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You have to give a title for the block, at least an empty one with: `\begin{block}{}`